# I have legs but cannot walk

Tags: riddle

> I have eyes, but cannot see.
>
> I have hands, but cannot work.
>
> I have legs, but cannot walk.
>
> Kids like me very much.

What am I?

Comment: Did you mean 'I have eyes' or 'I have an eye'?
I have hands or I have a hand?
I have legs or I have a leg?

Comment: Sorry for my grammar mistake.

Comment: @Smart It's not much better. It's either an eye (one), or eyes (many).

Comment: @RadoslavHristov eyes

Comment: I have two legs from the hips to the ground - when I lift them I walk around :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you are

> a doll

Because

> dolls have eyes, hands and legs - but they cannot actually see, work or walk (except for in our imaginations). Children often like them, but I don't know for sure if they like children!

Comment: Answer can be extended to any toy with eyes, hands, legs.
Kids likes toys so of-course that satisfies too.
>!i.e. barbie, teddy bear, robot.

Comment: Well, changing the rules on the fly should be against the rules. What's more, there are mechanical "walking" dolls so technically the walking part is incorrect.

Comment: @RadoslavHristov - it happens (usually because the question setter did not realise quite how broad their puzzle was, and in such cases it is actually encouraged). There have been far more extreme examples. Anyway, no doubt some modern artist somewhere has made a portrait that can walk about :p

Answer (score 7):

May be Answer is

> Scarecrow

It have hands, eyes and legs but non of them working

Comment: Right, but not expected answer.

Comment: kids like scarecrow very much?

Comment: This ans was given before this line"Kids like me very much." added in the puzzle,

Comment: Even so, the scarecrow from The Wizard of Oz is often cited as a favorite character :)

Answer (score 3):

> A full size portrait showing a person with eyes, arms and legs.

I have eyes but cannot see.

> The person on the portrait has eyes but can't really see

I have a hands but can't clap.

> It has arms and hands but can't clap.

I have a legs but cannot walk.

> It has legs but can't walk with them.

Comment: good thinking but not correct answer!!!

Comment: @Smart OK, take two - I've changed my answer.

Comment: Suddenly this got very creepy

Comment: @6005 How's that?

Comment: @RadoslavHristov Describing a portrait of a person in this way gives me creepy vibes. I can't explain it other than that.

Comment: @6005 Unfortunately gif-style portraits are at present available only in the "Harry Potter" books.

Comment: *facepalm**facepalm**facepa...

Comment: @Snickbrack what's with the facepalm?

Comment: that's just as correct as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

> A table bearing a [clock powered by French-fried potatoes](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Potato-Clock).

I have eyes but cannot see.

> [Potatoes have eyes.](https://www.wonderopolis.org/wonder/do-potatoes-see-with-their-eyes) 
> Admittedly, the cooking process probably obliterates them.

I have a hands but can’t clap.

> (Analog) clocks have hands but can’t clap.

I have a legs but cannot walk.

> The table has legs but can’t walk with them.

Kids like me very much.

> Kids like French fries.